# When was BIOS routine E820 introduced?

Tags: bios

On the web, there are a number of BIOS routine references which describe all the available routines at boot time. However, I haven't found any reference which describes when various routines were introduced.

Does routine E820 (INT 15) go all the way back to the original IBM PC? This seems unlikely, since it uses 8 bytes for the base address of each physical memory region, which would have seemed incredibly extravagant at that time. So when did it come to be?

Comment: No, it wasn't available until about 1994 (with Phoenix BIOS 4.0) and was targeted at Pentium processor based systems.

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86) has a remark that suggests it  came into its own on all PCs in 2002.  No better sourcing here but the reference to > 4GB tracks with the timeframe

Comment: @zedman9991 It was available on all new PCs in 2002, but that interrupt exception was available on Phoenix 4.0 BIOSes since the mid-90's and pretty much coincided (more or less) with Pentium class systems.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, that's an answer; why not enter it as one?

Comment: Because I don't have a canonical source to use as a reference. Although [Ralph Brown's Interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1741.htm) says 0xE820/Int 15h appeared in Phoenix 4.0. I know from experience this particular BIOS appeared around the introduction of Pentium's which would have been in the 1994 time frame, but as for a definitive source on the last part, I can't find a specific document. There is a Phoenix 4.0 document from 2000 referencing 0xE820 in the ["Phoenix 4.0" guide](http://www.esapcsolutions.com/ecom/drawings/PhoenixBIOS4_rev6UserMan.pdf)

Comment: I did find [some evidence](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/windows-nt-3-1-and-os2-memory-detection/) with a bit of digging. Windows NT 3.5 was the first Windows OS to use Int 15h/ax=e820h. If you look up the [release date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_3.5) for Windows NT 3.5 it is said to be September 1994. [Windows NT 3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_3.1) which apparently didn't support it was released in 1993. Since  `Int 15h/ax=e820h`was first found in Phoenix 4.0 BIOSes I think it is safe to that a timeframe around 1993-1994 might be reasonable.

Comment: This question would have been better suited on Retrocomputing: http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Laurel, I didn't know about the retrocomputing SE. I will use that site next time for "historical" questions.